# How to hide empty elements on page? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am learning RoR
I am trying to build simple image-board

Problem I have is that on my show post page there is reply comment even user didn't created one

```
<div id="comments">
    <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>
```

This is what I use to render comments

```
    <div id="post_wrapper">
      <%= image_tag comment.image.url(:medium) %>
      <h2 id="post-content-index" style="font-size: 20px;" ><%= simple_format(comment.body).gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></h2>
      <h1 id="post-username-index"><%= comment.name %></h1>
    </div>
```

This is _comment.html.erb

```
#post_wrapper , #post{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
}
```

This is styling for comments

My question: Is there a way to hide `

```
<div id="comments">
    <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>`
```

when it is empty

What it looks like:

[image]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def landing
    @post = Post.last
end
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("posts.created_at desc")
    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def faq

end
def mod

end
def rules

end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :username, :content, :image)
end
```

end

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name,:body, :image))

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

end

Comment: Post your controller's code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but let me take a pass at it. If you want to hide that div when there are no comments present, try wrapping it in a ruby if statement (inside the .erb code inclusion tags) that will only show that section if there are comments on the post object.

From your example it's not clear if comments is a many to one association or something else, but this code assumes it is an association and as such even when there aren't any there, it's the [].

```
<% if @post.comments.length > 0 %>
    <div id="comments">
        <%= render @post.comments %>
    </div>`
<% end %>
```

If I misunderstand, please clarify and I'll try again...

Answer (score 0):

Some of this answer depends on what you consider an 'Empty' comment. The Comment model appears to have name, body, and image properties. The way that I would handle this would be to use scopes in the model to designate what 'Empty' means, and then call the scope in the view.

First the scope:

```
class Comment
  ...
  scope :not_empty, -> { has('name').has('body').has('image') }
  scope :has, ->(column) { where("#{column} IS NOT NULL") }
  ...
end
```

Next the view:

```
<%= render @post.comments.not_empty %>
```

Putting the scope this way will allow you to decide what not_empty should really define. The above requires all three properties to be filled. If you wanted only body and image required, then you would define not_empty as:

```
scope :not_empty, -> { has('body').has('image') }
```

Note that this is an AND request, OR would need another scope:

```
scope :has_at_least_one_of, ->(props){ 
  where(props.map{|p| "#{p} IS NOT NULL" }.join(' OR ') 
}
```

And would be called:

```
scope :not_empty, -> { has_at_least_one_of(['body', 'image', 'name']) }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I actually fixed it

I replaced

```
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

with

```
<%= render @post.comments.limit(250) %>
```